# Is it possible to define the wavelet phase difference for only one signal?

Tags: signal-processing, wavelet

The wavelet phase difference between two signals $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ is derived using the real and the imaginary part of cross wavelet transform $W_{x,y}$. (Let us consider e.g. the Morlet wavelet as mother wavelet.) More in details, the wavelet phase difference is defined as follows
$$
\theta_{x, y}=\arctan \left(\frac{\Im\left(W_{x, y}(\tau, s)\right.}{\mathfrak{R}\left(W_{x, y}(\tau, s)\right.}\right)
$$
where $\theta_{x, y} \in[-\pi, \pi]$, and with $\Re[z]$ and $\Im[z]$ we refer to the real and the imaginary part of $z \in \mathbb{C}$. According to the value of $\theta_{x, y}$, it is possible to establish if the signal co-move positively (negatively) and which signal is leading (lagging) the other one.

Is it possible to define the wavelet phase difference for only one signal? E.g. as happens for cross correlation and auto correlation.

Comment: Autocorrelation is not a phase difference, and cross correlation is for two signals. It’s not clear what would be the meaning of the phase shift for a single signal. It has to be relative to something

Comment: @Aksakal maybe relative to itself (e.g. a shifted version of istself)?

Comment: you're trying to call an autocorrelation a phase shift. it's not.